# Flutter ssh2 2.2.3 package build errors (ssh2:compileDebugJavaWithJavac)

Tags: android, flutter, gradle, libssh2

I try to add connectivity to my Flutter project, my main goal is to support Android first. When I add ssh2 package I get error.
Steps I follow:

1. `flutter pub add ssh2` for which output is:
   `Changed 3 dependencies!`
2. `flutter pub get`
3. Push 'play' button the output is:

> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception
> Execution failed for task ':ssh2:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.  Could not resolve all files for configuration
> ':ssh2:debugCompileClasspath'.
> Failed to transform bcprov-jdk15on-1.69.jar (org.bouncycastle:bcprov-jdk15on:1.69) to match attributes
> {artifactType=android-classes-jar, org.gradle.category=library,
> org.gradle.libraryelements=jar, org.gradle.status=release,
> org.gradle.usage=java-api}.
> Execution failed for JetifyTransform: C:\Users\mkaczmarczyk.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.bouncycastle\bcprov-jdk15on\1.69\91e1628251cf3ca90093ce9d0fe67e5b7dab3850\bcprov-jdk15on-1.69.jar.
> Failed to transform 'C:\Users\mkaczmarczyk.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.bouncycastle\bcprov-jdk15on\1.69\91e1628251cf3ca90093ce9d0fe67e5b7dab3850\bcprov-jdk15on-1.69.jar' using Jetifier. Reason: IllegalArgumentException, message: Unsupported
> class file major version 59. (Run with --stacktrace for more details.)

I tried everything proposed in https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/fix-execution-failed-for-task-appcompiledebugjavawithjavac-in-android-studio/
as well as "Invalidate Caches/ Restart" and similar.

When I try to run example from package's author I do it successfully up to version 1.6. With higher releases I get the same error.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same error, this was helping:

[Flutter ssh2 2.2.3 package build errors (ssh2:compileDebugJavaWithJavac)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69513201/flutter-ssh2-2-2-3-package-build-errors-ssh2compiledebugjavawithjavac)

You need to update to gradle 7.0.2